# Android error- Working Directory: null Environment: null

Tags: java, android

I am trying executing this bat in android studio and I get the below error. I am not sure how to resolve this as I am new to android. can anyone please suggest what needs to be tried.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start /src/androidTest/CopyFiles.bat");
```

**Error:**

```
java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [cmd, /c, start, /src/androidTest/CopyFiles.bat] Working Directory: null Environment: null
at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:211)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:174)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:247)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:190)
```

Comment: Are you trying to run a batch file on Android?  If so you can't do that, android runs on linux not windows.

Comment: not on android, but a batch file that has an adb command to pull files from sdcard.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is simply that you are trying to run the `cmd` command on a Linux (which Android actually consists of) system. `cmd` is the short name for `cmd.exe` which is located in `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe` but not on Linux/Android phones. So it does not exist. If you are only trying to copy files, you could do this with Java.

If you are trying to extend your application with plugins or extensions you may want to have a look at BeanShell. Running `.bat` files is not easy on Android. You would at least have to run a shell script instead. Just Google around to see how you can run shell scripts on Android and how they differ from Batch files.

**Long story short:** CMD is not found on your Android phone because it's a Windows program. Because it cannot be found you get this error.